# How to read a text file into jtextarea in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, bufferedreader, filereader

Here is my code:

```
try {
    String textLine;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("ad.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
    while((textLine=reader.readLine()) != null) {
        textLine = reader.readLine();
        jTextArea1.read(reader, "jTextArea1");
    }
}
catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.err.println(ioe);
    System.exit(1);
}
```

And my .txt file contains the following:

> contig00001  length=586   numreads=4
>   CGGGAAATTATCcGCGCCTTCACCGCCGCCGGTTCCACCGACGAACGGATACTGCGtGaa
>   ggCCGCGATCCCGTCggaCGGAAAaCGCCcTGGCCCGGGAaCATACCGTTCGGGCCGCCA
>   AGTGTTATAGCCGGACCACTTGTCAGAACATTTCCaaTCCGAAGATGTGAGTtCGGAAGg
>   TAAAAGCCCGACAAGTTGCGCGgTGAATTTACCTTtACcGCACGATATGCGTCCGTATTA
>   AaGAAAaGTTCGAAATTATCAGTAAGGCCGACCTGAAaGCTGACCGGGAGTTCAACAAAA
>   TCTGCATCACCcGGgTCACGGTCGAAATTGCTGTACGCGGCGCTGAACGTAAATTCACCC
>   TTTcTAAGGGTGTCGCcGTCGTAAACCGTAAaCAaGCCGGTAGCGCCGCCCATCGGGCCG
>   CCGGTACCAACCGTCGGTGCCGTGTTTCTtGCATCATTGTCCGATCGAGCGTTCTCGTCC
>   GCTTGTGCAAaTCCTGCAaTAGCTAACGTGAAAACGATCAGAGCTGTTGTAAATACTCTA
>   TAAGCGAGATTCATCACATTCCTCcGCCGAAATAAAAAGTTAATTt
>
> contig00002  length=554   numreads=4
>   TGCGCCAaCCGCGCTCTtCATAAaTGGGCACTGCTCCCGATGGCCgACTCGGGCGGTTCG
>   CCATGAGATCTTTGCCtACCcAGgAaCtCACcACCAAGTCTGATTGCTGTGTGTTTtCTT
>   CAAGTCCCTATTTCTATTCtCTTtAATGGAACCCGTAGGAAACCCGTGTAGGACGCGGGA
>   aCCGCACTTgAAGGGGGAGGCGCGGGGTACCGGtCCGGGAACGTACGGGTACCGGCGGGG
>   gAGGGGAGGGGGACCgCTCCGGGAAGGCCAGGGGACGGATTGGGGAAGGgCGGGTACCGA
>   AGCGGGgAAaTGGGggAaCcGGCGAGAGGGTTCCTCGCTAAGTGGGGGAAATaGGGGAAA
>   GGTTGACCAGTGGTtCCCcGCTCTCGTAACATGCCTCAGATAGCGCCATCCGCTGTACCT
>   GGtcaggtcGctggcaacttcggccgagcaggtgaacccgaaaggtgagggtcagtgtga
>   cacaccaaccgaacaccgacgaggcaagcgtaggagccggcgtggccgcgcccggcggcg
>   ctgaggactcctcg

But shows the output by skipping the first two lines.

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need the while loop, or the readLine method. Just call `jtextArea1.read(reader, "jTextArea1")`

**Edit**: update following your comment. If you want to skip all lines starting with >, you will need to read the file manually and then append each line to your textArea.

So something like:

```
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    if (!line.startsWith(">"))
    {
        jTextArea.append(line + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for rly,but i want to skip all lines starting with symbol">"

Comment: thx sir,i have written following code:       try { 
File file = new File("c:\\ad.txt");
 FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String textLine;
          while((textLine=reader.readLine())!=null){
              if(!textLine.startsWith(">"))     {
        jTextArea1.append(textLine + "\n");     } 
              jTextArea1.read(reader,"jTextArea1"); 
         } 
 }
 catch (IOException ioe) {
 System.err.println(ioe);
 System.exit(1);
 }

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("filename.txt");
txtarea.read(reader, "filename.txt"); //Object of JTextArea
```

You need only the above two lines to read from a file and put it into JTextArea...

Answer (score 0):

`textLine = reader.readLine();` is called twice...

Fixed:

```
try {
    String textLine;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("ad.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);

    while((textLine=reader.readLine()) != null){
        // textLine = reader.readLine(); // Remove this line
        jTextArea1.read(reader, "jTextArea1");
    }
}
catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.err.println(ioe);
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: The `while` loop and `readLine()` in its condition are also not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Correctly is:

```
try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("tablica.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);

    do {
        l.read(reader, null);
    }

    while ((textLine=reader.readLine()) != null)
        ;

}

catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.err.println(ioe);
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to load anything into `jTextArea`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must have been solved by the time, yet there's still no answer to the question *why the first two lines are skipped*.

You create `reader` and then read the first two lines from the file, remaining lines are loaded into `jTextArea1`.

Your code:

```
/* 1 */ while((textLine=reader.readLine())!=null){
/* 2 */     textLine = reader.readLine();
/* 3 */     jTextArea1.read(reader,"jTextArea1");
        }
```

Line 1 reads the first line from the file. Then in the body of while you read the second line from the file at line 2. Line 3 reads the rest of the file into `jTextArea1`.

On the next iteration of the while loop, `reader.readLine()` returns `null` since the file is completely read.

---

To load text in a `JTextComponent` use its [`read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) method as suggested by [Phill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6356168/572834) and [Bhushankumar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14014265/572834).

The second parameter to `read` is not used by `JTextArea`, so it's safe to pass `null`. This second parameter is usually used to store to URL of the loaded file to resolve relative references, for example links in an `HTMLDocument`.